# Wicket 8 wicket setDefaultModel clashes with setDefaultModel

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-8

After upgrading from Wicket 7 to Wicket 8, I encounterd multiple erasure warnings in IntelliJ.

E.g. when using `AjaxLink` IntelliJ complains

> 'setDefaultModel(IModel model)' in
>   'org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer' clashes with
>   'setDefaultModel(IModel model)' in
>   'org.apache.wicket.IGenericComponent'; both methods have same erasure
>   yet neither overrides the other

Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Which version of IDEA do you use ? It is interesting why no one else noticed this so far. Since javac is happy about it it is not a real problem. Maybe IDEA is to blame

Comment: @martin-g appears to be generics-related, not IDEA-related

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error occurs when you do not give `AjaxLink` a generic type. For example:

```
new AjaxLink("id")
```

Instead of something like:

```
new AjaxLink<Void>("id")
```

AjaxLink has the following definition:

```
public abstract class AjaxLink<T> extends AbstractLink implements IAjaxLink, IGenericComponent<T, AjaxLink<T>>
```

The ancestor class is `MarkupContainer`, which defines:

```
public MarkupContainer setDefaultModel(final IModel<?> model)
```

And it implements `IGenericComponent`, which has generic types `<T, C extends IGenericComponent<? super T, ?>>` which are assigned the types `<T,AjaxLink<T>>` and defines the method:

```
Component setDefaultModel(IModel<?> model);
```

Now, I'm not entirely sure if I fully understand the problem, but somehow due to the lack of generic types, the compiler cannot figure out that the implementation from `MarkupContainer` (which returns `MarkupContainer`) is covariant with the method defined in `IGenericComponent`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. That fixed it, but why does it only happen in Wicket 8?

Comment: `IGenericComponent` did not define `setDefaultModel` in Wicket 7

Comment: There is something wrong with this opening sentence "This error occurs when you do not give AjaxLink a generic type. The error occurs when you do:"  One of these has to be negative case, they are both saying the error occurs regardless of whether T provided.

Comment: The code sample is supposed to be part of the second sentence, in which case they both describe the same case, but I'll edit the answer to clarify